# ExtJs time chart showing incorrect labels

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts, extjs4, extjs-chart

What's wrong with ExtJS 4.0.7 charts? In this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JPEEv/377/

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
  storeId: 'MyStore',
  fields: [{
    name: 'date', type: 'date'
  },{
    name: 'duration', type: 'float'
  }],
  data: [
    { date: new Date(2014,1,1), duration: 0.3}, 
    { date: new Date(2014,1,2), duration: 0.2}, 
    { date: new Date(2014,1,3), duration: 1.5}, 
    { date: new Date(2014,1,4), duration: 0.7}
  ]
});

var chart = Ext.widget('chart', {
  renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
  width: 800,
  height: 400,
  store: 'MyStore',
  axes: [{
    type: 'Time',
    position: 'bottom',
    fields: ['date'],
    dateFormat: 'd.M'
  }, {
    type: 'Numeric',
    position: 'left',
    fields: ['value']
  }],
  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    axis: ['left'],
    xField: 'date',
    yField: 'duration'
  }]
});
```

1. there are 5 date labels instead of 4
2. the third value is 1.5, but the limit of y axis is not adjusted
3. is there a way to place labels in the gaps between the labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You used `type: 'Time'` for your X-axis which builds a continuous
   time axis and puts labels at arbitrary places. If you want 1
   label per column, use `type: 'Category'` and format string values
   instead of date values.
2. For the Y-axis replace `fields: ['value']` by `fields: ['duration']` so that it has the same name as your field in the store.
3. The framework doesn't provide such configuration, I haven't found it in their [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/charting).

Comment: Is there a way to format those labels in chart config? Something like in the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JPEEv/384/

Comment: @mirelon No built-in formatting, you should write your own function like `function formatDateString` and use it so `{ date: formatDateString(new Date(2014,1,1)), duration: 0.3}`